# Upbar for SE/SO chat

Tags: script, chat

[rlemon](https://stackapps.com/users/8939/rlemon) and [myself](https://stackapps.com/users/7380/amith-kk) created a Userscript which moves the userbar on top... so that you can see more stars!

## UpBar

The goal of this project was to gain more space on the sidebar of the StackExchange Chat System for user stars to be displayed.

The User List is moved to a auto-hide bar in the top left of the chat.

[image]

*mouseover the visible part of the UpBar to display the user list for the room*

[image]

[*December 10, 2011*](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/commit/a2c4c64c4a377f188bee5db909df8ffef886953e) - added **stick/unstick** button to the menu bar. press **stick** to keep the menu from hiding on mouseout.

Click [here](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/raw/master/StackExchange/Upbar/bar.user.js) to install

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/tree/master/StackExchange/Upbar)

Enjoy.

---

**Licence:** GNU GPL v3

Comment: A little jQuery hint: `$('#present-users')` is much nicer than `$(document.getElementById('present-users'))`, and means the same thing

Comment: @balpha albeit uglier, `$(document.getElementById('present-users'))` performs 30% faster. In production code I wouldn't do this.. I would leave out the `$()`.

Comment: @rlemon To each his own. I, for one, have yet to see a piece of code where a 30% performance increase in element-by-Id look up even remotely started to possibly look like maybe making a difference.

Comment: point is: if you can produce an increase in performance, without taking a hit on development time; why wouldn't you?