# More Stars - Userscript that frees up room so you can see more starred messages

Tags: script, chat

Since I've never written a GreaseMonkey script before, I borrowed heavily from [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2740/upbar-for-se-so-chat) and basically played around with it until I got what I wanted. So credit to them for helping me get there.

### More Stars

I don't like having my chat window fill the full monitor, but I found that with my preferred browser window size I usually could only see 5 or 6 of the starred messages in chat. I was getting sick of it and decided to make this script that allows me to hide the room info (which I'll be happy to never see again) and the user list so that I can always see starred messages without having to resize my browser window.

The Room info is hidden by default (because how often do you read it, really?), and the user list is shown. For my preferred window width, that's enough to see all starred messages. There are toggles so that the room info and user list can be hidden/shown.

[image]

Get it from the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/more-stars/pmheggccgdfihmlaphhjdlhccganhfmi)

Comment: +0.5 freehand circles, and +0.5 for more stars.

Comment: I presume is GNU GPL v3?

Comment: I don't know anything about licensing. If you're asking me if you can copy it, modify it, distribute it, burn it, do a naked dance on it, or anything else you want, then sure, have it!

Comment: I love this extension. Could you upload it to the Chrome Web Store? Chrome no longer allows arbitrary user scripts to be run. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've now added it to the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: @Sterno: Total legend.

Comment: The version in the web store only seems to work, for me, on chat.stackexchange.com (i.e. not chat.stackoverflow.com), but it should be same version, right? Hmm...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I might have screwed that up when I was prepping the manifest for the web store. I really didn't have much clue what I was doing. I'll check it out when I get home from work.

Comment: @Sterno: Teehee okay appreciated. I really rely on this extension; I hadn't realised how much until Google went schizo about non-store extensions. Tried to work around it by switching to Chrome-dev, but that's buggy as heck so I switched back

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've uploaded a new version which should work now. It was indeed the manifest file that got me... I'd only included chat.stackexchange.com there

Comment: @Sterno: You, my friend, are a wonderful human being. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Support for the SSL chat would be great :) (`https://chat.stackoverflow.com/...`)

Comment: I can't seem to install the original userscript... is http://www.nat20s.com/scripts/morestars.user.js broken somehow?

Comment: Oops, yeah. I stopped paying for that domain so it's gone. You can get it on the [Chrome store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/more-stars/pmheggccgdfihmlaphhjdlhccganhfmi) though.

Comment: It seems broken at the moment. For example, visiting https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec does not yield any options to hide users nor room informations.

Comment: Thanks, not working in Arqade's chat either. I'll look into it when I have some time.

Comment: Until I get around to fixing this (and maybe even after that), I recommend using @fredley's Porkchat script: [Porkchat: A Chrome extension with lots of chat tweaks!](https://stackapps.com/questions/6266/porkchat-a-chrome-extension-with-lots-of-chat-tweaks)